# What is the suggested method of playing video indefinitely in a browser? (for weeks or months a time)

Tags: javascript, html, flash, video, html5-video

I'm working on a system with few devices and screens that should be able to run indefinitely, or at least 2-3 days. One of those is a promotional screen that runs in a fullscreen browser and has some text and a video playlist that should loop forever.

Currently I'm using jquery [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) as my playlist video solution and I'm having a problem that it crashes after longer period of time. I'm not quite sure how to test it, but I left it running over the weekend just to find it not loaded today.

So my question is:

- Which solution would be best for a video playlist that has to loop forever?

Comment: It's hard to say as it's not a very common scenario. You could check when it played over all the videos in the playlist and reload the page completely

Comment: Exactly the way you did but without memory leak. No, to be serious: I don't think you need any Flash or plug-in for this task (assuming HTML5) then please share your code, it should be nothing more than 20 JS lines (then my tip is drop jPlayer, what's for?!)

Comment: @JonasGrumann I'm not too keen on refreshing the browser. Only time I'm willing to refresh the browser is during the middle of the night when nobody is around which will probably fix everything, but I'd rather have it be able to run for few days just to be sure.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Haha, yeah, everything without memory leak :D. I'm not sure how to make browser delete video he loaded after he jumps to another video. I'll drop jPlayer, it just seemed like an easy solution at that time.

Comment: Let browser manage that stuff, any decent browser shouldn't leak when you change video (and it shouldn't be anything more difficult than create a new `<video>` to replace old one, looping through your _playlist_).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti http://pastebin.com/scmRcKr9 I'll test this, also added console.log on each repeat so i can see how many there were if it crashes again

Comment: Yes, something like that (but invert video/script order unless you use document.onload).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yeah, script is under video tag, inverted while c/p -ing from code

Comment: uhh had a brain fart on the last pastebin, here's the right one http://pastebin.com/aSVFPMGt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the code that worked

```
<video id="videoPlayer" src="../../Content/data/video_01.m4v" style="width: 1280px; height: 720px;" autoplay controls />

<script type="text/javascript">
  var videoArray = [ "../../Content/data/video_01.m4v",  "../../Content/data/video_02.m4v", "../../Content/data/video_03.m4v" ];
  var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
  var videoIndex = 0;

  videoPlayer.onended = function () {
    videoIndex++;

    if (videoIndex >= videoArray.length) {
        videoIndex = 0;
    }

    videoPlayer.src = videoArray[videoIndex];
  }

</script>
```

Note: It crashes after +/- 14hours on Opera on a Sony TV, but works perfectly on a PC that runs Chrome in fullscreen (which I'll have running on site).

EDIT 1:
Also added at the end of the script in case a video fails to load (which happened once).

```
  videoPlayer.addEventListener('error', function (err) {
      err.preventDefault();
      videoPlayer.onended();
  });
```

EDIT 2:
this last part (adding eventlistener on error) is the key for everything. Apparently when it crashed it crashed only because it couldn't load a video and stoped. So I'd suggest having this.

Comment: You may _try_ to rebuild video tag each time (instead of update its src attribute) - in case it leaks some memory each time it loads a file and assuming browser will perform a good cleanup when elements are disposed). well a lot of assumptions...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti You know that ancient proverb: "don't try to fix things that aren't broken". PC + Chrome work perfectly fine. No sign of any memory leakage. I'll be sure to test it over the weekend once more, hopefully no bugs slip into production :)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti haha, why is that?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti deadline in 3 weeks :)